# jquery: can't get appendTo on parents() to work, may not understand parents() method?

Tags: jquery, prepend, parents, ancestry

The following code block does not work:

```
$("<span class=\"ideacount\">").prependTo(chapter.parents(".chapter")).each( function(index) {
    $(this).html((parseInt($(this).text() || 0)+1)+"");
});
```

where 'chapter' is a node that in this case is nested 5 elements deep among other elements of class 'chapter'.

Whereas this code behaves as expected, but is not what I want (it prepends to all other branches of the tree structure as well instead of just the ancestry of 'chapter'):

```
$("<span class=\"ideacount\">").prependTo(".chapter").each( function(index) {
    $(this).html((parseInt($(this).text() || 0)+1)+"");
});
```

Edit: to elaborate:

chapter.parents().length

is 10 (5 spans of class 'chapter', 5 li's)

chapter.parents(".chapter").length is 0!?

Comment: Could you show an excerpt of your HTML, that includes the nodes/elements you're working with in this code, and explain what should happen step-by-step?

Comment: My apologies, seems i've suddenly figured it out and it was pure user error.  It was due to the weird structure of the html and the fact that contrary to what I said, there are actually no parents of 'chapter' class and the code was behaving true to that.

Answer (score 0):

Try closest instead of parents.

```
$("<span class=\"ideacount\">").prependTo(chapter.closest(".chapter")).each( function(index) {
    $(this).html((parseInt($(this).text() || 0)+1)+"");
});
```